# ruby on rails - deprecation warning about Base::cookier_verifier_secret

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cookies, upgrade, deprecated

Upgraded an app from 2.3 to 3.0 and now getting these.
What's the best option to fix this so that when it's eventually removed I won't have problems.?

`DEPRECATION WARNING: ActionController::Base.cookie_verifier_secret= is deprecated. Please configure it on your application with config.secret_token=. (called from <top (required)> at /home/durrantm/Dropnot/webs/rails_v3/linker/config/initializers/cookie_verification_secret.rb:7)`

What value should I be setting `secret_token` to?
Where in the code shold I set it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix was to change:

```
config/initializers/cookie_verification_secret.rb
```

Changing:

```
ActionController::Base.cookie_verifier_secret=
```

to

```
ActionController::Base.config.secret_token=
```